# Which STM32 supports USART IDLE line detection?

Tags: stm32, uart

I have a project with an STM32F302R8 realizing a communication protocol via a USART based on IDLE line detection.

I used `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA` located in stm32f3xx_hal_uart_ex.c.
Now I need to port the project to an STM32F103C8 and I face a problem - there is no such function in the 103 drivers; there are no _ex.c files in the driver directory at all.

I figured out some chips don't support IDLE line detection. I haven't found any information about the technology even in the STM32F302x8 datasheet (p 3.18), which obviously supports it.

How do I know if a chip supports the technology? What is the easiest way to replace the `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA` function in my code?

Comment: You can look at the list of the USART interrupts in the *reference manual* (not the datasheet) of the MCU. There is one for idle line detection. See page 886 of `rm0365` from [here](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f302c8.html#documentation)

Comment: The STM32F103 most definitely *does* support UART IDLE detection. Refer to the [Fine Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0008-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), section 27, where it specifically refers to the Idle Line detection in the UART.

Comment: And the latest HAL driver code for the STM32F103 I've just download through STM32CubeMX does have a `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA` function in stm32f1xx_hal_uart.c

Comment: Somehow I've got an old version of this file, thank you very much, brhans. After recreating the project I've got the function. And also thanks to Eugene for clarify where to look at.